# Move Magento to new domain

Tags: magento, installation

I am trying to move a Magento site from a subdomain over to it's main domain and I'm having trouble. A friend made this guide and I followed it to a tee (I think anyway)

I done a back up in Magento and uploaded to my main domain and then -

1. Make a backup of the existing DB (PhpMyAdminexport).
2. Copy the files over to a new server (It’s faster archive them, if you have an SSH access, instead of FTP).
3. Create a DB on a new host.
4. Import the existing DB dump on a new server (PHPMyAdminimport).
5. Verify that Magento is using the right settings for DB at: \app\etc\local.xml
6. Check a newly created DB. 
   Find table: ‘core_config_data’. 
   Edit the record for ‘web/unsecure/base_url’.
   Edit the record for ‘web/secure/base_url’.
   If you don’t do that, the site will always be redirected to an old location.
   For example,  for both change:  “http(s)://allmyoffers.co.uk/”  to http(s)://.co.uk/
7. Remove the contents of ‘var\cache’ directory.
8. The new Magento site should be ready now.

Does anyone know were I've went wrong ? Here's my site - www.perfumecow.com

P.S I only have limited code skills so please if you write basic code talk so I can understand :)

Cheers

Chris

Comment: This type of question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow, as it's not a programming question. You should take a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento and see about getting a proper place to put these kind of questions

Answer (score 12):

Answer is you are missing a forward slash in your url settings.

Change  `‘web/unsecure/base_url’` from `'http://www.perfumecow.com'` to `'http://www.perfumecow.com/'`

And change `‘web/secure/base_url’` from `'https://www.perfumecow.com'` to `'https://www.perfumecow.com/'`.

(dont forget to mark it as answered if it fixes the matter)

Comment: Glad i could help, the world of coding one forward slash could mess up an entire site...

Comment: you don't need to change the title, just marked @GershonHerczeg 's answer as answered and we all know that it has been answered